# Is it possible to set two MX records for one domain?

Tags: mx-record

I've seen articles about "different subdomains for different MX records".

But I want two records for the same domain, `@abc.example` for example.

Originally, I used **Live Mail(MSN)** to host my emails, and already have MX setup for it.  Now I want to use some of the **Google App** features, so I need to setup MX for Google Mail.

Can both of the two work together and well?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

While you can set up more than one MX server for a given domain, this is purely a backup function to specify another server to receive mail when one server goes down. It's not possible to let two totally different services both handle your mail for the same domain, and IMHO it doesn't make any sense to even try. If you like Google's features better, switch to Google, otherwise you have to live with what Live Mail offers.

What might work is to forward mail from Live Mail to another domain hosted by Google, but then you would need to manage two separate services.

Comment: Actually, it is. You can have each mailserver *also* checking for any domain mail from each other, in case any senders are using the lower-priority MX when the higher-priority one is available.

Comment: Have fun convincing Google and Microsoft that you want to do this with their service...

Comment: Certainly not something you would do with hosted email. If you were running your own however, that's how it can be done.

Comment: @mfinni What a load of bull.  Google Mail certainly supports forwarding.

Comment: @Tom - ok, i have little experience with hosted email. I was granting Sven that it might be more complicated, but he was apparently wrong and I shouldn't have humored him.

Comment: @mfinni: Where was I wrong? When a mail is delivered, it's delivered, and if you have two MX servers delivering mails for the same domain in their respective mail store, your config is seriously fracked up. As long it's not delivered, you can do quite a lot with different MX servers, but this wouldn't help with the problem at hand.

Comment: MX servers don't send mail for a domain, they receive it. If you have two MXs receiving mail for a domain, as long as they all end up in one mailstore, what's the problem?

Comment: "this is purely a backup function" except if both MX records have the same preference: "MX records contain a preference indication that MUST be used in
   sorting if more than one such record appears (see below).  Lower
   numbers are more preferred than higher ones.  If there are multiple
   destinations with the same preference and there is no clear reason to
   favor one (e.g., by recognition of an easily reached address), then
   the sender-SMTP MUST randomize them to spread the load across
   multiple mail exchangers for a specific organization." (RFC5321)

Answer (score 2):

Dual MX records are used for backup purposes, i.e. if you list more than 1 MX record for a domain, any host attempting to deliver email for that domain will only attempt such delivery to 1 MX at a time.

In order to achieve a dual delivery as described in your question you will need an SMTP service that receives email for your domain/s, and that SMTP service would perform delivery to multiple endpoints, e.g. for each message it delivers once to Google Apps and once to Live mail.

This is not common and almost certainly not a good idea, maybe you can clarify what it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Dual delivery is common enough that Google Apps supports it and shows you how you can set it up. It's just not done through MX records.