# Can i Set Two Different server MX Record for one Domain

Tags: email, email-server, mx-record, gmail

Suddently, Today one of my client asked me to setup google mail services for his business, currently he is using zoho mail and approx 5-6 user email working on zoho, now he purchased google mail services for 1 user and want to host only 1 email account from his zoho mail to google mail and for rest 5 users account he wants to be continue on zoho it self..

is there any possibilities to host both mx records of zoho and gmail for single domain.

any suggestion , it will be thankful.

Comment: Yes, you can set multiple MX records for one domain. But as stated in [this SF answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/212432/1-domain-2-mx-is-it-possiable-to-set-two-mx-record-for-one-domain) or [that SF answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/464303/is-it-possible-to-add-2-different-mx-recorid-of-entry-of-different-registrar-in?rq=1), what your client wants to do is not (easily) possible.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't about MX records but about routing mail once it is accepted. You'll have to either alias from Google or Zoho but definitely do not set both as MX for the domain.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have multiple `MX` records but that is for redundancy with one mail service.

Depending on how you specify the priority values, you would either (different priorities) consistently have all mail delivered to one service and any addresses not existing there be permanently rejected or (same priority) have mail arbitrarily delivered to one service or  the other and any addresses not existing there be rejected permanently.

Ideally you would avoid getting into the situation you describe in the question, otherwise have one service accept all mail and selectively forward some addresses.